# Remotely calling Java from php

Tags: java, php

I have a java program that runs on a couple different computers and I want to be able to be able to access them remotely.  I don't need to do anything crazy, just some very basic input output (get and set type stuff).  I could write a client type application and set each program to a server with RMI and do it that way but I will not always be on the same computer and do not want to have to carry the .java file around with me.

I'd prefer to write a simple php webpage that I can access from anywhere and have some very basic buttons that could send the commands to the different Applications and receive back some output.

Problems is that it would probably impossible to get my host to load anything other then php onto the server where I'd host my webpage.

Does anyone have any ideas? I've tried googling it and found a couple things out there that sort of sound like what I need but the more I look into them they seem to not be what I wanted after all.

Comment: where are you hosting the java stuff?

Comment: Its a basic digital signage program I wrote and is in use at a couple of our locations.  It runs fine and I can always remote desktop in and make the changes to play lists / transfer over any updates I make to the program.  The problem is I cant remote desktop in during the day while they're playing so I want to be able to access them and do basic stuff like force the player to start over, or pass it a new video name to play, and have it add to the list. I can do this with command line commands while it is running but I want to be able to do it from anywhere.

Comment: What does this question have to do with Java RMI? given that you don't want to use it?

Comment: There are thousands of different ways to approach this. First you need to identify some more specific constraints in having the two applications talk to each other and then go from there.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do this right I'd suggest looking at a Java web framework (I use [Play!](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.1/home) myself) to create a RESTful web service and then sending requests from your PHP code that will fetch JSON data.

A framework like Play will make it very easy to get a REST web service running. Just create some wrappers that invoke your existing java code and call `renderJSON` to output the result.

From the PHP code you'll [issue the request using curl](http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2008/Using-curl-and-PHP-to-talk-to-a-REST-service) and then read the response using [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) which will turn it into a handy php variable.

This also has the advantage that either end can be changed without the other noticing, as long as the json data format is kept the same.

Answer (score -1):

Based on the way you described your setup you'll probably run into routing issues trying to reach your Java apps from your PHP host. I'd recommend you try something else: have your Java apps frequently check with your PHP app if there are any updates. You can simply use a Java URL connection and a timer:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html

Comment: I thought about using the timer and have it check an ftp server for a text file with commands, but I was hoping for a more instant way of sending commands.  I was hoping with php I could give it an IP and port and say send this command but it would need to be understandable by the java program.  Having it receive back from the java program is not as important right now.  I can have it post a text file to an ftp server with its playlist when ever a playlist change is made.

Comment: @kyle: well you could implement something that receives a http POST request from the hosted server and then determines what CLI command to issue and issues it. Then you would jsut have to use the curl functions in php to send the post request.